# How do I get a slider in Word doc?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

How can I get a visual element such as a slider into a Word document so that I can make use of it to visually represent a scale of 1-100 ?

I was thinking of an element such as this: 
[image: sliders]

I am fine with any such element that will visually represent a numeric value.

Comment: An image of a slider or a dynamic control?

Comment: First....What version of Word...Second I have never heard of putting dynamic controls into a Word document.

Comment: @Ramhound inserting a chart can be tied to dynamic data. You can also insert OLE Objects. Not to mention linking data with VBA. Just depends on how involved you want to get.

Comment: word 2010, and i'ld like to be able to not use an image but something i can slide to set the value. something dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing pre-built that I know of that you can easily add to Word.

Only options I can think of:

1. Create a slider in JavaScript, take a picture of that and insert it. We use the [jQueryUI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) in our application. You can use JSFiddle to create and test out options. You would need to create a slider you like and then copy in an image (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mz486/) for example).
2. Program a custom control. This could be done in .Net or with something that supports OLE.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but apparently if you have Visual Studio you can [Add Windows Forms Controls to Office Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b86d6w07.aspx):

> You can add Windows Forms controls to Microsoft Office Excel and Microsoft Office Word documents at design time in document-level projects. At run time, you can add controls in document-level customizations and in application-level add-ins. For example, you can add a ComboBox control to your worksheet so that users can select from a list of options.
>
> 1. Create or open an Excel Workbook project or Word Document project in Visual Studio so that the document is visible in the designer. For information on creating projects, see [How to: Create Office Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0es5szt7.aspx).
> 2. In the **Common Controls** tab of the **Toolbox**, click the control you want to add, and drag it to the document.

If you check the [list of controls that can be embedded in Word documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.word.controls.aspx), there's a [TrackBar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.word.controls.trackbar.aspx) that seems to be just what you need.